# How do I use/combine ssh agent forwarding and xfce4?

Tags: ssh, git, arch-linux, vagrant, xfce4

I have a vagrant arch linux box with ssh agent forwarding, which is working fine, when i run: 
`startx` (`ssh -T git@example.com`: Hi mc_plectrum! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.).

But running startxfce4 with nothing else changed, leads to: Permission denied after running `ssh -T git@example.com`.

What am I missing here?

Comment: XFCE is probably starting its own `ssh-agent` during `startx`, which overwrites the connection to you forwarded agent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

xfce has its own ssh-agent. 
It can be checked if the output of `echo $SSH_AUTH_SOCK` in a vagrant ssh session is different from the output within xfce4.

**SOLUTION**:
The following disables the agent, which else would have been started during startup of every xfce4 session:

```
xfconf-query -c xfce4-session -p /startup/ssh-agent/enabled -n -t bool -s false

xfconf-query -c xfce4-session -p /startup/ssh-agent/type -n -t string -s ssh-agent
```

**Hint:** You have to use `vagrant ssh` in order for ssh-agent to work (just `vagrant up` is not sufficient). You can use: vagrant `ssh -- "startx" -X`, so that the X Server is directly started.